# SQL Update Statistics Not Working Have to Drop and Create

Tags: sql, statistics

Not sure SQL question is appropriate here.

I have a strange situation, UPDATE STATISTICS on a 72-million-row narrow table has no improvement for queries at all, say take 60 seconds. It comes down to 3 seconds after dropping the index and recreating it.

This table has

- one cluster index
- one non-cluster index consisting two Int fields

Comment: So if you `update statstics` query take 60 sec, but if you `drop/create` index take 3 sec ?

Comment: That means your index has been corrupted.

Comment: Juan, it's SQL Server.

Comment: Rahual, if so just run DBCC Checktable, right?